# Handling relational mongoose schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a project one part of which is media library. User can create folders and upload files into any of the folder.

My folder/file structure is virtual meaning that folder exists only in database and files are under one physical folder but the metadata for each file contain the level inside folder structure.

For now all folders and files are under one schema and I can retrieve child folders/files of selected folder and I can retrieve single folder/file and also I can retrieve files by their type. And it works very well, but )

I wan't to separate each file type into its own schema because each file type will have it's own set of attributes. And now I don't know how to link those schemas to my resources schema.

Will it mean that in order to retrieve child folders/files of selected folder I will have to query each schema separately and combine each result into one? It seems that it's not very good idea but I can't figure out how to handle it.

Is there any common approaches for handling this type of scenarios?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are saving to db the file metadata and the folder structure, right?

If so maybe you can use populate to can tell mongoose to link each file type Schema with:

```
SomeTypeSchema = new Schema({
    // ... metadata fields ...
    resourceParent: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'ResourceModelName'
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('SomeType', SomeTypeSchema);
```

Then you can do:

```
var type = SomeType.find({field: 'somefilter'})
    .populate('resourceParent')
    .exec(function(err) {
        console.log(type.resourceParent.name);
    });
```

Documentation: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html